# IP aliasing with Python 2.7 on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ip, sudo

In my application I need to do add and remove IP addresses to/from a network interface on the fly. But I couldn't find a secure and reliable way of doing this.

I thought of using `subprocess(["ip addr add ..."])`, but the `ip` command requires `sudo` privileges and I don't want to elevate the privileges of my application. Neither do I want to hardcode the password. I feel like I'm out of options.

Is there a Python module that eases these kind of operations (an example implementation would be great).

If `subprocess` is my only option, is there a way to make this secure? (I thought of compiling a separate binary with hardcoded password to be used from my application, but that didn't sound correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do, you *almost* certainly will need `sudo` privs to modify an interface.  A python module can't change that for you.  The most secure way will be to make a user or group specifically for running this script under, and grant it passwordless sudo **while restricting it to only the commands it needs** (`ip` and such).  Here is how you can allow only certain commands:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

Comment: "A python module can't change that for you." I admit, I was looking for magic :)